# How do I execute an external JavaScript every few seconds?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I like to load an external JavaScript once every 10 seconds or so. Or whenever the body of the page is clicked(if so, I need to run the script only if few seconds are passed).
Even if anyone points me to the documentation., it will be more than sufficient.

Comment: setInterval would be a good start.

Comment: Normally you would load a Javascript once, and then maybe execute it every 10 seconds.

Comment: Did my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 10000); //will execute the alert every 10 seconds.`
Please find an example here.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval

Comment: Actually it will only do so if you dismiss the alert. The alert is blocking

Comment: Yes, it was just an example to show how a body automatically invokes a function every n seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can try bellow code snippet :

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<body onClick="refreshPage()">

this page will refresh in every 10 seconds
</body>
</html>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

script.js

```
function refreshPage(){
    window.location.reload();
}

setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload();
 }, 10000);
```

Comment: That's an external javascript which isn't on my domain. I cannot edit it.

Comment: BTW, I don't need the page to be refreshed.